# $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of continuous funcitons, then $\{x\in [0,1]: \sup_n |f_n(x)|=+\infty\}$ can't be like $[0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of real valued continuous funcitons on $[0,1]$, then the set $E=\{x\in [0,1]: \sup_n |f_n(x)|=+\infty\}$ can't be like $[0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}$.

I think this question is related to Baire Theorem. $E=\cup_{n=1}^\infty \cap_{m=1}^\infty \{x\in[0,1]: |f_n(x)|\geq m\}=\cup_{n=1}^\infty F_n$, $F_n$ is close set.$[0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}$ has no inner point....... I don't know how to continue.

Comment: What does "like" mean when you say "like $[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$"?

Comment: $E$ can be $[0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your union and intersection in the wrong order.

$$\bigcap_{m=1}^\infty \left\{ x\in [0,1] : \lvert f_n(x)\rvert \geqslant m\right\} = \varnothing$$

for every $n$, since $f_n(x)$ is some finite real number for every $x$. In fact,

$$E = \bigcap_{m=1}^\infty \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left\{ x\in [0,1] : \lvert f_n(x)\rvert > m\right\}.$$

Now look at that and Baire's theorem.

Comment: Yes, I got a big mistake, if so, how do we use the Baire thorem?

Comment: What can you say about $$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left\{ x\in [0,1] : \lvert f_n(x)\rvert > m\right\}\,?$$ And what follows about $E$? It may be helpful if you consider the complement of $E$ (remember de Morgan's laws), if you are only familiar with the "countable union of closed sets" formulation of Baire's theorem.

Comment: I know Baire theorem has two kinds: the countably intersection of dense open sets is also dense and If the countable union of closed sets has no inner point, then every such closed set has no inner point. If $[0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}= \cup_m \cap_n \{x\in [0,1]: |f_n(x)| \leq m\}$, because LHS has no inner point, so every set $\cap_n \{x: |f_n|\leq m\}$ has no inner point, that to be a null set.

Comment: Of which category is the countable union of nowhere dense sets?

Comment: It is the firt category.

Comment: And $[0,1] \setminus \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: You mean $[0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}$ or $[0,1]\setminus \mathbb{Q}?$ I don't know and I am sorry that I am not familiar with the category theory.

Comment: I mean $[0,1]\setminus\mathbb{Q}$. And Baire category isn't category theory. If you prefer, use "meagre" and "nonmeagre". The point is that if $([0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}) \subset E$, then $[0,1]\setminus E$ is meagre (of the first category). But $[0,1]\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ is non-meagre (of the second category), so $E = [0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ is impossible.

Comment: Yes, I understood now, thanks a lot.